# How to get the element an event was bound to in React, since event.currentTarget is null?

Tags: reactjs, events

If I run the example below in React, `this = undefined` and `event.currentTarget = null`.

How do I get the element the event was bound to?

```
  <div onMouseEnter={(event) => console.log(event.target)}>
    <span>HELLO</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: You might see `null` on the console because the console output is not exactly synchrous, and older React uses [event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html), which nullifies all event properties. Which react framework version are you using?

Comment: @Martin That was exactly the problem. I just logged the whole event object and then it is null.